# How to access to a textLabel in a static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

After much searching and reading I unfortunately do not come from the following. I want to use static tables to display certain data. (Are there better options?)

In my view I first put an onion picture with a container view underneath. The container view again refers to a Table View Controller.

I made an outlet from the cells and then I thought I could easily adjust the text.

Now I want to change the text of the fields in the table, but unfortunately I do not succeed.

When I start the app then the table is completely empty as seen on the screenshot.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image: Overview]

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data: [String] = ["Muis", "Aap", "Koe", "Vis"]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return data.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let iets = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = iets

    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: To use static cells, make sure you've set the table view **Content** to **Static Cells** rather than **Dynamic Prototypes** in your storyboard, and remove the override methods from your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done after a lot of testing and reading. I have create a segue to the statutable class.

```
if (segue.identifier == "myEmbeddedSegue") {
        let childViewController = segue.destination as! hondDetialTableViewController
        childViewController.hondId = hondData["hondId"]!
    }
```

In this segue I send only the hondId, everything else i ask entities.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use static cells

- Forget dequeueing `UITableViewCell` instances and all tableview data source and delegate methods.
- In Interface Builder select the table view and select **`Static Cells`** from the `Content` popup
- Drag the amount of static cells you need into the canvas
- In the view controller declare `IBOutlet`s and connect them directly to the UI elements in the cells

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your way of thinking for this one. You do not own the cells, the `UITableView` does. It will provide cells as it seems fit by using your implementations of `UITableViewDataSource`:

- `func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int`
- `func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int`
- `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Normally, the texts (your actual data) would be held in a list available to this data source.

**Example:**

```
var data: [String] = []

// Other functions

func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER")
    cell.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Now, if you want to change this cell's text, all you have to do is update your data list and reload the data.

Comment: This is also possible with multiple cells, each with its own identifier ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But do note that you only need different identifiers if your cells are different custom cells (cells with nothing but text don't really need a custom class). If so, you just need to have your data keep the type of cell as well as the information it will present.

Comment: Despite the fact that what you said is true, OP asked about the static table view and in static table view, tableView will not dequeue cells anymore, all cells are stored and can be hooked with IBOutlet inside the viewController

Comment: What I not understand is why I get the follow error: Cannot assign to property: 'textLabel' is a get-only property by line cell?.textLabel = data[indexPath.row]

Comment: @wouter You need to do cell?.textLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]

Comment: It does not work at all. I have assigned the TableViewController.swift file to the tableview class of the table. As soon as I try to start the app I get this message: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. If I then delete the reference to the TableViewController, the cells appear to be working again ....

Does this have to do with the fact that the table is in a container view?

Comment: @farzadshbfn I have tried to make outlets from the cells and from the table cell. But I did not manage to do anything with this. Even now I have the idea that it is because the tableview is in a container view. https://imgur.com/ec9o5td

Comment: @Wouter I would need to see the current version of the code to be able to help you with that. SIGABRT errors are rather generic and happens in many cases. Your tableview should be able to be in a container view without any issues. Is your data initialized when you are loading the content of the tableView? When is the content loaded? Do you make sure that `cellForRowAt` returns a cell instance?

Comment: Static tableview cells are ONLY available in UITableViewControllers, if that’s what you contained in another view, it should work just fine, but it won’t work otherwise

Comment: As other answers brought it up, you don’t have to use static cells and in the mean-time, implement dataSource methods, I think that’s what confuses the tableview

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp I have updated the code. possibly the entire test project can be found here. https://woutervdpol.stackstorage.com/s/udv2sn2MvM99Erh

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this is not at all how UITableView works.  The UITableViewCell that you define in the Xib/Storyboard within the tableview are just "models" or templates, they don't actually exists until you dequeue them.

You can read how UITableView works here: http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/

You have to return numberOfSections > 0 if you want anything displayed in your tableview; similarly, that section has to also have numberOfRows > 0 otherwise again, nothing will be displayed (ok, maybe headers and footers if those are properly setup).

At any rate, cells are only accessible after you dequeue them.  Creating an outlet in a XIB to a UITableViewCell is useless in most cases.

You can explore other options, such as UIStackView, or maybe what you need is just plain custom UIView with labels that you properly set and layout using NSLayoutConstraints.  There are plenty of resources out there, this is just one I quickly Googled for you to get started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=de0sthle44I

Good Luck.